# LDAP Unable to start openldap for windows

Tags: ldap, openldap

I watched youtube online as reference to install openldap on windows,

I also followed the tutorial on zytrax.com

```
C:\OpenLDAP>slaptest -f slapd.conf -F slapd.d
```

5c9eec00 using config directory slapd.d, error 0
config file testing succeeded

there is this part "Conversion to slapd.d is trivial. After modifying the slapd.conf file as required simply create a new directory/folder called slapd.d. Open a command line (dos box for us oldies), navigate to c:\OpenLDAP (or wherever you put your installation) and enter:"  in which I don't understand, what do I need to configure in slapd.conf

```
C:\OpenLDAP>slapd -d 8 -h "ldaps://localhost/ ldap://localhost/"
5c9ef038 OpenLDAP 2.4.42 Standalone LDAP Server (slapd)daemon: bind(2) failed errno=10013 (WSAEACCES)
5c9ef038 daemon: bind(3) failed errno=10013 (WSAEACCES)
5c9ef038 slapd stopped.
5c9ef038 connections_destroy: nothing to destroy.
```

How do I get my ldapserver to start running ?

Comment: You need to allow `slapd` and `slaptest` to bind to ports 389 and 636.

Comment: how do i go about doing that ? during installation i installed with 3899 and 6366

Comment: Well either that didn't take or you need to look at your firewall rules.

Comment: i try to bind it on the same machine

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and my issue was that the ports were already open by another service. Try specifying other ports when starting the slapd server.

```
slapd -d 8 -h "ldaps://localhost:6866/ ldap://localhost:3899/"
```